# I have an issue with my ecommerce web application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, e-commerce, sanity

Can anybody help me with this error? I followed an ecommerce example application, but at the end, I encountered an error when I clicked on "Shop Now." This is the message I received:
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'image' of 'product' as it is null.

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
pages\product[slug].js (19:10) @ image

```
const { image, name, details, price } = product;
     |        ^
  20 | const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  21 | const { decQty, incQty, qty, onAdd, setShowCart } = useStateContext();
  22 | const handleBuyNow = () => {
```

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const query = `*[_type == "product"]{
slug{
                    current
}
}`;

  const products = await client.fetch(query);
  const paths = products.map((product) => ({
    params: {
      slug: product.slug.current,
    },
  }));
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: "blocking",
  };
};
export const getStaticProps = async ({ params: { slug } }) => {
  const query = `*[_type == "product" && slug.current == '${slug}'][0]`;
  const productsQuery = '*[_type == "product"]';

  const product = await client.fetch(query);
  const products = await client.fetch(productsQuery);

  return {
    props: { products, product },
  };
};
export default ProductDetails;
```

Thank you

When you click on 'Shop Now', it is supposed to open the cart directly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of de-structuring your properties like this

```
const { image, name, details, price } = product;
```

you should access them like this,

```
product?.image
```

This will help you avoid your error and also you can conditionally check if a particular property exists or not.